# Parallelizing a function to write to global variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to figure out the best way to parallelize a program like this:

```
global_data = some data
global_data2 = some data

data_store1 = np.empty(n)
data_store2 = np.empty(n)
.
.
.

def simulation(global_data):
    
    retrieve values from global datasets and set element of global datastores
```

such that I do something like pass `list(enumerate(global_data))` to a multiprocessing function, and each process sets elements of the global data stores corresponding to the received (index, vlaue) pair. I'm running on a high performance cluster with 128 cores, so I think parallelization is preferable to threading.

Comment: You can use managed lists here

Answer (score 0):

If you use a multiprocessing pool (e.g. a `multiprocessing.Pool` instance) with its `map` method, then your worker function, `simulation`, just needs to return its result back to the main process which will end up with a list of results that will be in the correct order. This will be less expensive than using a *managed list* to which the worker function adds its result:

```py
import multiprocessing

def simulation(global_data_elem):
    # We are passed a single element of global_data
    # Do calculation with global_data_elem and return result.
    # The CPU resources required to do this calculation must be sufficiently
    # high to justify the additional overhead of multiprocessing (which is
    # not the case for this demo):
    return global_data_elem * 2


def main():
    # global_data is some data (not necesarilly at global scope)
    global_data = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    # create pool of the correct size
    # (not larger than the number of cores we have nor the number of tasks being submitted):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(min(len(global_data), multiprocessing.cpu_count()))
    # results are returned in the correct order (task submission order):
    results = pool.map(simulation, global_data)
    print(results)

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
```